# Поиск элемента в дереве

Tags: prolog, turbo-prolog

Здраствуйте! Подскажите, как написать правила, чтобы при поиске элемента в дереве, можно было вывести и "Yes" и "Not".
На данном этапе при отсутствии элемента ничего не выводит(

```
domains
tree=empty;tree(integer,tree,tree)
predicates
tree_member(integer,tree,integer)
init(integer)
initon(integer)
print(integer)
clauses
tree_member(X,tree(X,_,_),0):-init(Y),tree_member(X,tree(X,_,_),Y).
tree_member(X,tree(X,_,_),1):-write("YES!"),!.                                     
tree_member(X,tree(_,L,_),S):-tree_member(X,L,0),!.
tree_member(X,tree(_,_,R),S):-tree_member(X,R,0). 
init(1).
initon(0).
print(1):-write("YESSSS"),!.
print(_):-write("NOT").
goal
init(D),
write("Enter number:"),nl,
readint(H),nl,
write("Search: "), nl,
tree_member(H,tree(3,
tree(2,empty,empty),tree(5,empty,empty)),D),nl,
print(D)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, нужно вывести Yes если искомый элемент есть в дереве и Not если нет? Я бы сделал tree_member предикатом, а вывод вынес наружу:

```
...
clauses
    tree_member(X,tree(X,_,_)):-!.
    tree_member(X,tree(_,L,_)):-tree_member(X,L).
    tree_member(X,tree(_,_,R)):-tree_member(X,R).

goal
    write("Enter number:"),nl,
    readint(H),nl,
    write("Search: "), nl,
    write("Search: "), nl,
    tree_member(H,tree(3,
       tree(2,empty,empty),tree(5,empty,empty))),
    write("Yes"); write("No"). % Если вызов tree_member "вернул" True, выводим Yes, если же Fail - то No. Точка с запятой означает логическое 'или'.
```

На "живом" турбо прологе не пробовал, но по идее должно работать.

Comment: да, все правильно, спасибо)